# REGEX for alternate characters in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a string `mystring`. I have to replace the alternate characters with `x` so that final output is `mxsxrxnx`. All the alternate characters starting from 2nd position are replaced with `x`. I can do it with loop but is there a Regular expression for that or a better way in PHP? Please help.

Comment: This smells a bit like homework, or an interview question. Which ever it is, you should really do it yourself, not let others do the work for you. Anyway. If you have made it work using a loop and just want to know if there is a better way, you should post it in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @CodeZilla What do you mean by **alternate characters** ?

Comment: @LuFFy edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a reset match meta-character `\K` you are able to do it:

```
.\K.
```

[Live demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/9hCikb/1)

PHP:

```
echo preg_replace('/.\K./', 'x', 'mystring'); // mxsxrxnx
```